# THREE.JS MaskPass works in Chrome on Mac but not on Windows 7

Tags: windows, google-chrome, three.js, webgl

I created a simple test of EffectComposer of THREE.js for inverse masking an object and to blur the background.  The test works perfectly in Chrome on Mac... but on windows it fails... no masking is happening, no matter what I do.  Same code path but drastically different result.

It basically does:

```
composer.addPass(renderPass of source 1);
composer.addPass(renderPass of source 2);
composer.addPass(inverse maskPass of source 2);
composer.addPass(vblur);
composer.addPass(hblur);
composer.addPass(clearMaskPass);
composer.addPass(vingette);
```

Does this sound familiar to you?
Any clue what I have missed on the windows platform for masking to not work?

many thanks in advance.

Comment: please describe the problem better, any error's you may see, what does work etc.

Comment: Interestingly, I've just found out it works perfectly in Firefox on Windows 7.  So only Chrome 29.0.1547.66 is having issue with Stencil Buffer.  I am not seeing any error in the developer console.

Comment: The intent is to combine two scenes into one.  One scene is the background, the other a foreground object.  The inverse maskPass will create a stencil buffer that basically masks out the object.  Both vblur and hblur applied after the Mask will only affect the background until a clearMaskPass is applied.  But in Chrome on Windows, this is not the case. blur is applied to both foreground object and the background.  The same code works perfectly in Chrome on MacOSX and in Firefox on Windows 7 where only the background is blurred.

Comment: i dont really no three.js, (is that the library for 3d and animations?) however you should edit that into your question if you want a good answer.

Comment: Upon further investigation, looks like the culprit is Chrome browser on Windows.  Open this example (http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_advanced) with (1) chrome on windows, (2) chrome on macosx, and (3) firefox on windows, and you can immediately see only (2) and (3) work as expected.   Unfortunately, the chrome browser from dev channel still has the same issue.